# How can I get count of distinct rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, distinct

My query looks like:

```
select distinct col1,col2,col3,col4 
from tab1;
```

How can I get the count of the rows that will come as output when I execute the above statement? ...or how to add `count()` to above statement?

Comment: **TURN OFF YOUR CAPS LOCK** please!! Writing in **ALL CAPS** is considering shouting at readers, and it's rude and offensive

Comment: After that statement, @@ROWCOUNT contains the row count

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
    select distinct col1,col2,col3,col4 from tab1
)
select count(1) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

`@@ROWCOUNT` returns what you need...

Example usage:

```
declare @resultCount AS INT

select distinct col1,col2,col3,col4 
from tab1;

SELECT @resultCount=@@ROWCOUNT

PRINT @resultCount
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1,col2,col3,col4) FROM tabl`